# Twiddle table computing

Tags: performance, c

I'm trying to optimize this [twiddle computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twiddle_factor) function:

```
void twiddle(int N)
{
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
     twiddle_table[i].re = (float)   cos((float)i * 2.0 * PI /(float)N);
     twiddle_table[i].im = (float) - sin((float)i * 2.0 * PI /(float)N);
  }
}
```

where `N = 4096` size of twiddle table and could be bigger!

And then, I did the following:

```
void twiddle(int N)
{
   int i;
   float Tconst;
   Tconst = 2.0 * PI /(float)N;
   for (i=0;i<N;i++)
   {
      twiddle_table[i].re = (float)   cos((float)i * Tconst);
      twiddle_table[i].im = (float) - sin((float)i * Tconst);
   }
}
```

But, I'm getting a performance of 340,000 cycles for the `for` loop, which I think is bad.

Any hints that could enhance the performance of this function?

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. What does it mean to "twiddle" something? Where is your `twiddle_table` defined? You didn't show all of your code. Also, what does `340 000` cycles for the for loop mean, when we don't even know the value of `N` or the size of the twiddle_table?

Comment: While the OP certainly *should* have explained himself, Google quickly told me that "twiddle table" is an established jargon term related to the implementation of FFTs (fast Fourier transforms). See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twiddle_factor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The optimization you made manually is most likely already noticed and implemented by the compiler.

Instead, you should notice that \$\cos\frac{2\pi k}{N} - i \sin\frac{2\pi k}{N} = e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{N}k}\$, and replace multiple invocations of `sin` and `cos` with multiplications. Naively:

```
    complex base = { cos(2.0 * PI / N), -sin(2.0 * PI / N) };
    twiddle_table[0] = { 1.0, 0.0 };
    for (i = 1; i < N; ++i) {
        twiddle_table[i] = twiddle_table[i - 1] * base;
    }
```

In the production code you need to pay attention to the accumulation of numerical errors, and once in a while fall back to direct computation of `sin` and `cos` (or `cexp`).

Of course, if your compiler doesn't support `complex` type, you's have to implement complex multiplication manually.

Another optimization comes from the inherent symmetry of the table, e.g. \$cos\frac{2\pi k}{N} = \cos\frac{2\pi (N - k)}{N}\$, so you only need to compute half of the table; there are more symmetries you may exploit.

PS: That said, I strongly recommend to precompute it once for largest possible `N`. Notice that it can be reused for any power of 2.

Comment: "In the production code you need to pay attention to the accumulation of numerical errors," - this is VERY important as multiplication quickly grows the error!

Answer (score 2):

A standard trick to reduce the error accumulation in vnp's code is to notice that the real part of base will be close to 1; we can use the multiple angle formula to compute base-1 (with base as in vnp's post) more accurately as

```
base_1 = -2*t*t + I * sin(a)
```

where

```
a = 2.0*PI/N 
t = sin(a/2.0)
```

(I is the square root of -1). 
Then update your table with

```
tab[i] = tab[i-1] + tab[i-1]*base_1.
```

Though this more computation, it will have less rounding error.

Unless hardware rules it out you should consider computing base as doubles, and accumulating the complex exponentials in doubles; you can use one variable W say with

```
W += W*base_1
```

then stored W in tab[i] -- hence converting it to float. 
Again more computation but less accumulation of error.

Answer (score 1):

this line:

```
Tconst = 2.0 * PI /(float)N;
```

will be performed in double due to the 2.0 to perform it in float, change the 2.0 to 2.0f

extract the expression:

```
(float)i*Tconst
```

to assign a float variable, inside the top of the for() loop and use that variable in the actual calculations

please show the definition of: twiddle_table[]

the parameter 'N' must NEVER be >= the number of entries in the `twiddle)table[]. Otherwise, undefined behavior will occur as the data is being saved beyond the end of the array, which can lead to a seg fault event

Since the data and results are float, the function: cos() should not be used. Suggest: cosf().

the function: sin() should not be used. Suggest: sinf().

Note: then there would then be no need to cast the result of the call to cosf() nor sinf() to `float